# lcd context switcher is not working in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I'm running Django with python3.2,  and recently discovered that fabric doesn't support Python3.

So I created a second virtual environment (fabric-env) just to run fabric out of.

Here's the fab --version output from the virtualenv:

```
Fabric 1.9.0
Paramiko 1.14.0
```

python --version

```
Python 2.7.3
```

My fab file looks like this (only relevant lines):

```
from fabric.api import local

def deploy(branch_name):
    with lcd('/var/www/finance'):
        local('git pull /home/user1/dev/' + branch_name)
        local('/var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/python3 manage.py test corefinance')
        local('/var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/python3 manage.py schemamigration corefinance --auto')
        local('/var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/python3 manage.py migrate corefinance')
        local('sudo service apache2 restart')
```

When I run this deploy function, I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/var/www/finance/fabfile.py", line 19, in deploy
    with lcd('/var/www/finance'):
NameError: global name 'lcd' is not defined
```

The fabric documentation says this function should be available.  It appears both fabric and Python are recent enough ( just to be sure fabric is not trying to run off of the different Python, I ran this function both inside and outside my virtual environment).

No hits on Google for the error message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not imported `lcd`. Add the following to the top of your file:

```
from fabric.context_managers import lcd
```